# Python command to get number of containers and vcores used by YARN running applications

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

## **1. Problem**

Based on this question and answer: [YARN shell command to get number of containers and vcores used by running applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174401/yarn-shell-command-to-get-number-of-containers-and-vcores-used-by-running-applic)
I use this YARN application command:

```
yarn application -status application_1511888377927_11169
```

to get result like this:

```
Application Report :
        Application-Id : application_1511888377927_11169
        Application-Name : some_funny_application.py
        Application-Type : SPARK
        User : hadoop
        Queue : root.MyQueue
        Start-Time : 1513086671642
        Finish-Time : 0
        Progress : 50%
        State : RUNNING
        Final-State : UNDEFINED
        Tracking-URL : http://10.0.0.100:1111
        RPC Port : 0
        AM Host : 10.0.0.100
        Aggregate Resource Allocation : 937266225 MB-seconds, 541312 vcore-seconds
        Diagnostics :
```

## **2. Question**

How to get this result using Python?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know believe that there is actually a "python command" to do what you are hoping to achieve here, however, python has built-in capabilities to execute commands on your host operating system.  Here's a simple example of something that you could run and test very easily from the interpreter:

```
    $ python # from the linux shell
    >>> import os
    >>> app_id = 'application_1511888377927_11169'
    >>> os.system('yarn application -status {appid}'.format(appid=app_id))
```

Depending on your requirements and level of sophistication that you require here, it would likely be more pythonic to approach this problem by using the `subprocess` module but `os.system` may be what you were looking for.